# How can I convert multiple columns to a single row and keep it in line with my other data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a set of data which lists out duplicates for an initial value (column A) I want to take the columns of data that reference the value in the cell in the corresponding row and transpose them.

Problem is there are multiple columns and the number of columns varies by the number of duplicates to the original value. So when I transpose I need it to essentially insert blank rows so all of the column data corresponds to the correct cell. Here is a screenshot with an:

[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has worked, or hasn't worked? Do you want a formula, or VBA (or either?)

Comment: So I have tried several different things. Copy & paste special transpose. Does not automtically move the rows down and just erases the existing data unless manually moved down. Its a significant number of rows 800+ with up to 20 duplicate values. I also tried using Kutools for excel to transpose the range. I also used an index range formula to try and change the data. VBA or a formula is fine as long as it works and you can tell me how and why it works. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trust this VBA code will meet your needs. It essentially does what a human would do manually, using B2 as a reference point for the first table. If your first tables top left cell isn't B2 then you will need to change all references to B2. By default the new table will appear 2 rows below the first. This could be changed changing the 'offset(j, 0)'. (e.g. offset(j+1, 2) would put the second table 3 down and 2 to the right).

Also note, the area beneath the first table will need to be blank or the new table will appear under whatever is there.

```
Sub Very_special_transpose()

'Calculates number of values
Dim Value1 As Integer 'row number of value 1
Dim LastValue As Integer 'row number of last value
Dim i As Integer 'number of values
Dim j As Integer

Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Select
Value1 = ActiveCell.Row

Range("B2").End(xlDown).Select
LastValue = ActiveCell.Row

i = LastValue - Value1 + 1

'puts in headers under first table
Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Value"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Reference value"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "Duplicates"

'Repeats copying process for each value

For j = 1 To i

Range("B2:C2").Offset(j, 0).Copy
Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
Range("B2").Offset(j, 2).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Your praises will be sung in the halls of my children for generations to come. I cannot thank you enough. I do have one additional question. Can you run this on a spreadsheet that has more than three main columns as long as the last one is the one I wanted stacked?

Comment: It should work for any number of values and/or duplicates (although it will take longer the more it has to do). The only limiter will be if the duplicate columns in the first table have gaps in them. If they do, then the gaps will appear in the second table (but going down). If that doesn't answer your question, a diagram may help my limited mind understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without a VBA code.
Just use goto insert-> pivot tables.
Then select design option in the tool bar above and select Report layout!! 
You can select any of the layouts you wish.